# Understanding the distance relationships in a Longitude and Latitude equation from an SQL query

Tags: sql, geolocation

In a PHP program that I did not develop I am able to enter, via a form, distance from a given US zipcode (radius in miles) from which to do a proximity search.

Let's take, for example, the city Gastonia, NC with a zipcode of 28054 and a radius distance of 10 miles.

The PHP code generates the SQL query dynamically.  Before it gets to that point it does its calculations behind the scenes and gives these values:

```
:minlat (Float) 35.084832880851
:maxlat (Float) 35.374297119149
:minlon (Float) -81.305653802747
:maxlon (Float) -80.951286197253
```

It also gives this distance:

```
:distance (Float) 16093.47
```

I cannot see or manipulate the code that generates these values given the distance I entered into the form. However, I can override the values of each of these calculated variables.

I understand the `:minlat` and `:minlon`, it's the central point of my zipcode. What I don't understand is, what is `:distance` and what relationship does it have to `:maxlat` and `:maxlon`?

What type of measurement is `:distance` given that it started as 10 miles in the form?

Obviously `:distance` added to `:maxlat` or `:maxlon` doesn't make any sense.

What I ultimately want to be able to do is take a `:minlat` and `:minlon`, which I have a database of point, and then search a certain `:distance`.

So, if I wanted to search 20 miles, that would be :distance 32186 ish, but how does that affect maxlat and maxlon?

If you are interested in the entire SQL query, it's:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, 
       node.nid AS nid, 
       node.created AS node_created, 
       'node' AS field_data_field_item_photos_node_entity_type,
       (COALESCE(ACOS(0.81684734668492*COS(RADIANS(location.latitude))*(0.15421945466762*COS(RADIANS(location.longitude)) + -0.9880366186544*SIN(RADIANS(location.longitude))) + 0.57685389156511*SIN(RADIANS(location.latitude))), 0.00000)*6370997.0816549) AS location_distance
FROM 
  {node} node
  LEFT JOIN {location_instance} location_instance ON node.vid = location_instance.vid
  LEFT JOIN {location} location ON location_instance.lid = location.lid
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') 
         AND (location.latitude > '35.084832880851' 
              AND location.latitude < '35.374297119149' 
              AND location.longitude > '-81.305653802747' 
              AND location.longitude < '-80.951286197253')
         AND ((COALESCE(ACOS(0.81684734668492*COS(RADIANS(location.latitude))*(0.15421945466762*COS(RADIANS(location.longitude)) + -0.9880366186544*SIN(RADIANS(location.longitude))) + 0.57685389156511*SIN(RADIANS(location.latitude))), 0.00000)*6370997.0816549) < '16093.47') ))
```

Table structure

```
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+----------+-------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default  | Extra |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+----------+-------+
| zip       | varchar(16)   | NO   | MUL | 0        |       |
| city      | varchar(30)   | NO   |     |          |       |
| state     | varchar(30)   | NO   |     |          |       |
| latitude  | decimal(10,6) | NO   | MUL | 0.000000 |       |
| longitude | decimal(10,6) | NO   | MUL | 0.000000 |       |
| timezone  | tinyint(4)    | NO   |     | 0        |       |
| dst       | tinyint(4)    | NO   |     | 0        |       |
| country   | char(2)       | NO   | MUL |          |       |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Sounds like distance is in meters. Latitude and longitude are position on the globe, four values making a (non-euclidean, on the surface of a sphere) rectangle . Most likely the central point is in the middle of that (not at min values, that wouldn't make any sense to me). Relationship of distance and coordinates is a bit ambiguous, since one distance implies a circle, while min-max coordinates imply rectangle.

Comment: @hyde thx for your input. The form I enter into has the fields ZIPCODE (value:28054); DISTANCE (value 10 miles).  Also, another default field checkbox selection is CIRCULAR (as opposed to rectangular).  I don't know what the equation is, but 10 miles is equal to 16093.47 'something.' (5 miles is half of that btw.) If I know minlat, minlong, and distance, how does that affect maxlat and maxlong? that is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: maybe it's a square and `distance` is the length of the sides?

Comment: also, 10 miles is about 16,000 metres making it pretty clear what the units of `distance` are

Comment: @user658182 a lot of the related questions contain SQL that looks a lot like what you pasted in, and the answers explain how it works. Start following those links (to the right of the question and comment area) and you may come to understand this calculation even without new answers on this question.

Comment: That's the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), reading up on it might answer the question for you

Comment: @KateGregory ah, then the conversion to miles must be done later in the program after this point.  I'm happy to let it do it's thing, but still trying to figure out what relationship :distance has to :minlat and :minlong. Obviously, some calculation is done given these three variables to derive :maxlat and :max long. If I can figure that out, then I can alter the :min values, apply a distance (if meters that's ok for the sake of the SQL query) and get the other values to complete the logic that the sql query uses.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the min-max lat-lon rectangle on some online map service? That should give you a good idea of what it really means.